# How to send via Wifi Direct from Android to PC?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, connection, wifi

I'd like to send files from my LG G3 to my laptop via Wifi Direct. But until now I just found tutorials and examples on how to send from phone to phone, is there also a way to send files from my phone to my pc? I don't want apps or programms, because I'd like to write them myself, but currently I don't have a clue how to connect my phone to my PC.
Thank You!

Comment: Why isn't usig just wifi ok?

Comment: Because I'd like to send my files wherever I am without an internet connection

Comment: Make your LG an hotspot. Let your laptop wirelessly connect with it. After that your apps can use that wifi connection.